# Using Text to Columns and make a graph from the selected range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

What I'm trying to do is first I have a CSV file which has an enormous amount of data.

The first column A has Date and time separated by a space as 03/11/2017 12:55:34.

I want to select the cells between two dates such as the range between **`03/11/2017 12:55:34`** to **`03/11/2017 15:55:34`**, then separate the date and time for the selected range using text to columns and finally plot the graph for the separated time and its corresponding value.

The code is working fine without doing text to columns conversion. But I don't know how to proceed with text to column conversion after selecting the range.

Hereby I have attached the code.

```
 Function getData()


Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long
Dim dataTable As Range

findrow = Range("A:B").Find("3/13/2017 15:49:57.108", Range("A1")).Row
findrow2 = Range("A:B").Find("3/13/2017 16:04:57.098", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
Set dataTable = Range("A" & findrow + 1 & ":B" & findrow2 - 1)
Set getData = dataTable
End Function

Sub SelectBetween()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

'Your data range for the chart
 Set rng = getData()
 rng.Select

'Create a chart
 Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

 'Give chart some data
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

 'Determine the chart type
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine

  cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Cells(1, 1).Value



  cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

  cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""CPU Processor Time"""

   cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
   cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100


 End Sub
```

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: Would you be interested in a potential non-VBA solution?

Comment: yes i wrote it with the help of some sources from Internet.i m very new to VBA so not aware of many functions.

Comment: yes.Any help would be appreciated.I mainly prefered VBA  coz its along with excel and i deal with enormous graphs every day in excel.So i wanted to save up my time

Comment: My example may be too simplistic depending on your needs, but is data I had handy.

Comment: You may wanna add an spread sheet image example to your question

Answer (score 0):

Non-VBA solution that may be applicable to your graphing needs. You may want to test on a copy of your data.

1. Filter your Date/Time information. In my example file, I have around 13,000 temperature readings filtered to 387 values to plot based on my range.

[image: Example of filter]

2. Change the format of the Date/Time information to just show time. Highlight the cells, and choose Time from the number format dropdown on the Home tab.

[image: Number Format]

3. You can chart the resulting column and its associated data.

[image: Example data and graph]

Date/Time data before number format change to just show time:

[image: Before change]